# 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'a'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Good afternoon! I'm learning flask and try to make something like authorisation but it shows me message "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'a'". I tryed to check my code but it didn't help me. If it's not difficult or you, please tell me where can be the problem. Thank you.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
        
            <input type="text" name="a"/>
            <input type="text" name="b" />
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">

        </form>
    </div>
    {% for m in get_flashed_messages() %}
     <div>{{m}}</div>
    {%endfor%}
    {{ Sum }}

    <a href="/login">Login!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
        
            <input type="text" name="a"/>
            <input type="text" name="b" />
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">

        </form>
    </div>
    {% for m in get_flashed_messages() %}
     <div>{{m}}</div>
    {%endfor%}
    {{ Sum }}

    <a href="/login">Login!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, abort
from flask.globals import request, session
from flask.helpers import flash, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'fddaeefgweef'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    Sum = ' '
    if len(request.form['a']) > 2:
        flash('completed!')
    else:
        flash('AAAAHHH')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.form['a']
        b = request.form['b']
        newSum = float(a)+float(b)
        Sum = str(newSum)   
    else:
        Sum = 'err'
    return render_template('index.html', Sum=Sum)



@app.route('/login/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if 'userLogged' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('profile', username=session['userLogged']))
    elif request.form['nick'] == 'hey' and request.form['password'] == 123:
        session['userLogged'] = request.form['nick']
        return redirect(url_for('profile', username=session['userLogged']))
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/profile/<username>')
def profile(username):
    if 'userLogged' not in session or session['userLogged'] != username:
        abort(401)
    return f'User {username}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    Sum = ' '
    if len(request.form['a']) > 2:
        flash('completed!')
    else:
        flash('AAAAHHH')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.form['a']
        b = request.form['b']
        newSum = float(a)+float(b)
        Sum = str(newSum)   
    else:
        Sum = 'err'
    return render_template('index.html', Sum=Sum)
```

you are asking about value of `a` from FORM data indiscriminately, but that does not make sense in case of `GET`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, now it's working. Thank you very much!